# APEX 3.2 Javascript Function Confirmation for 'Cancel' button

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I am looking to create a JavaScript function that will display a confirmation popup box when a user clicks on the ‘Cancel’ button in an APEX 3.2 application.

I want to ask ‘Are you sure you want to cancel this issue?’.  Show a ‘Yes’ and ‘No’ button.  If the user clicks ‘Yes’, send them to page 1.  If the user clicks ‘No’, keep them on this page (2).

I just need to know how to send the user to page 1 or keep them on page 2.  Many thanks!!!

```
function confirmCancel()
{
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this issue"?);
if (r==true)
  {
      Go to page 1
  }

else
  {
      Stay on page 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are maybe some functions in the [APEX 3.2 JavaScript API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/javascript_api.htm) that could be useful for you (`confirmDelete()` for example).

Else you can use apex.submit, passing an item with a specific value, then depending on that item value you can have a page branch.

Comment: +1 `confirmDelete('Are you sure you want to cancel this issue?','CANCEL');` would be perfect, combined with a condition branch to page 1 when request = 'CANCEL'

Comment: @Yann39 - Thanks for the link.  I will defiantly use that in the future.